# Merge corresponding values from column 2 into column 1 (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns in my pandas dataframe like this:

```
ID          Value1      Value2
ID1         1.00        0.12
ID2         2.00        0.98
ID3         3.00        0.41
ID4         4.00        0.69
```

I would like to merge them, so that the corresponding value from column 2 is merged into column 1:

```
ID          Value1      
ID1         1.00        
Value2      0.12
ID2         2.00        
Value2      0.98
ID3         3.00        
Value2      0.41
ID4         4.00        
Value2      0.69
```

It is seemingly an easy logic, but I simply cannot figure this out. Any idea/help out there?
Deeply appreciated.

Comment: I realize this is not a simple melt, you actually need some post-processing

Comment: If this generalizes to more columns, you might need to adapt the condition in the `mask`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) and post-process the columns:

```
out = (df
   .melt('ID', ignore_index=False)
   .assign(ID=lambda d: d['ID'].mask(d['variable'].eq('Value2'), 'Value2'))
   .sort_index().drop(columns='variable')
   .rename(columns={'value': 'Value1'})
)
```

Output:

```
       ID  Value1
0     ID1    1.00
0  Value2    0.12
1     ID2    2.00
1  Value2    0.98
2     ID3    3.00
2  Value2    0.41
3     ID4    4.00
3  Value2    0.69
```